# TIFF file can only be opened if downloaded through browser

Tags: raster, r, geotiff-tiff

I'm downloading a TIFF file from https://floodmap.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/getTile.php?location=060W030S&day=120&year=2021&product=3

When I download it in my browser I am able to successfully download it and open it. When I use a simple `download.file` command in R it downloads a file that is the right size but can't be opened.

When I run `tiffdump` on the two versions I see why, which is that the browser downloaded file has all the correct tags while the R downloaded one only has a subset of the tags and is missing some important ones like `StripOffsets`.

Here is an example:

```
download.file("https://floodmap.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/Products/060W030S/2021/MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif", "./MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif")
```

Comment: Please add a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @bugmenot123 I edited it to include the line of code.

Comment: And which file exactly do you download from the site? If you don't show *all the steps* that you take no one can guess what the problem is. ;)

Comment: If you run the line of code you get the exact file i downloaded put into the working directory.

Comment: If you just navigate to the URL in the command it'll auto-dowload the same file. That one should open but the one obtained through R doesn't.

Comment: Not sure what other steps to demonstrate.

Comment: Works for me. Your download.file and pasting the URL in your download.file into a browser or using wget at the command line gets identical files. MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif is 437506 bytes long. I don't see a link to any rasters beginning MSW from that web page portal in your first link though - only N/A in the MSW line of the table.

Comment: Found it under "14 Day composite"? Link there to the same file as in the download.file, if I download from clicking on the web site I get an identical file to your download.file. Not seeing anything anomalous here.

Comment: @Spacedman yes, that's right, but then when I try to open one (in QGIS or in R) the download.file one doesn't work. Using tiffdump I can see that the one that doesn't work is missing metadata and exiftool shows the same thing, but I can't fix it. I've tried it with ~100 files from that site and they're all unopenable.

Comment: Interestingly if I do `raster(url)` it works fine, so that might be the solution, but it doesn't save the file locally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the clue

Use `download.file(url, file_path, quiet = TRUE, mode = "wb")` as on Windows, it seems to be needed e.g https://community.rstudio.com/t/download-file-issue-corrupted-file/60844/2

The required part is the `mode = "wb"` option

Your issue is related to your OS. FYI, my R version is `R scripting front-end version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29))` on Ubuntu 64 18.04. When I run the following on the OS I can confirm that diff from files retrieved through R method and wget is empty: it means both files have the exact same content

```bsh
Rscript -e 'download.file("https://floodmap.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/Products/060W030S/2021/MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif", "./MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif")'

wget -O wget_MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif https://floodmap.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/Products/060W030S/2021/MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif

diff wget_MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif MSW_2021120_060W030S_A14x3D3OT.tif
```

Comment: the "wb" flag solves it, even though I'm running WSL :/ Thank you so so much.